# Android 6 Permission denied for Reading SMS?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, android-permissions

Hi I am developing ionic application which is reading users sms , in android 6 mobile phones It does not read SMS , Instead it shows the error , Permission Denied, How to Fix it thanks in Advance ?

I am Using

- cordova-plugin-sms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- install this plugin `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions@0.6.0`
- Just add this code into  `ionic.Platform.ready` it will ask one time permission   ..

  ```
  var permissions = window.plugins.permissions;
  permissions.hasPermission(checkPermissionCallback, null, permissions.R);

  function checkPermissionCallback(status) {
    if(!status.hasPermission) {
      var errorCallback = function() {
        ionic.Platform.exitApp();

      }

      permissions.requestPermission(function(status) {

        if( !status.hasPermission ) errorCallback();
      }, errorCallback, permissions.READ_SMS);
    }
  }
  ```